# How to select element preceded by specific XML comments using XPath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML, how do I select the `uid` element whose preceding-siblings are comments with normalized text value equal to "VID_1128" or "Some Title"? The problem here is that "Some Title" precedes two `<uid>` elements, so I only want to select the `uid` element whose value is `3333`.  Is this possible to do with XPath 1.0, and if so how?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<uids>
    <!-- Some Unique Text -->
    <!-- VID_2564 -->
    <uid>1111</uid>
    <!-- Some Title -->
    <!-- VID_8374 -->
    <uid>2222</uid>
    <!-- Some Title -->
    <!-- VID_1128 -->
    <uid>3333</uid>
    <!-- A Different Title -->
    <!-- VID_9581 -->
    <uid>4444</uid>
</uids>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with XPath-1.0 and the way to do it is the following:

```
/uids/uid[normalize-space(preceding-sibling::comment()[1]) = 'VID_1128' and normalize-space(preceding-sibling::comment()[2]) = 'Some Title']
```

There is one difference to your given objective:

> are comments with normalized text value equal to "VID_1128" **or** "Some Title"?

The above XPath expression follows the condition of `and` and not `or` between the two predicates. This has to be done to select only `3333` as result.

Using `or` instead of `and` would result in a nodeset with two values: 2222 and 3333 - and that's not what you wanted.

Comment: Indeed, I was curious about the `and` condition.